# meteorite local packages, having trouble setting the global namespace?

Tags: meteor, meteorite

My current project is at https://github.com/jimmack1963/localPackages.git.

I am trying to get this code to work:

```
console.log("You pressed the button, " + MyName);
```

where MyName comes from a package called simple, that is JUST LOCAL.  Per 6.5, am exporting via

```
Package.on_use(function (api, where) {
    api.add_files(['constant.js'], 'client');
  //below added per possible suggestion from Nathan, had no effect.
    api.use('constant.js', 'client');

    if (api.export)
        api.export('MyName');
});
```

Am trying to factor my code out to local packages.  This is not about publishing packages, but about using local ones, which is referred to in many places.  My package is simply trying to publish a string, MyName.  But the project wants none of it.  "MyName is not defined."

I copy the technique in 'Discover Meteor,' but it doesn't work for me, and I try other things.  Have had a lot of success in Meteor in general.

This spec seems to be changing.  I get the 6.5 export requirement, but easily find contradictory advise about the base project's need to add that project in smart.json (not the one in the package).  Most references don't list that as a requirement at all.

I've tried

```
{
  "packages": {
      "simple" : {
          "path": "packages/simple"
      }
  }
}
```

and putting it into git and trying from a different project:

```
{
  "packages": {
 "simple" : {
          "git": "https://github.com/jimmack1963/localPackages.git"
      }     

    }
}
```

For the latter, pleasingly, the installer was smart enough to burrow down and extract the package itself, ignoring the project wrapping it in the git project.  Nice!  So, I have the same problem when I install the package directly from git, still not published to the world.

- Ubuntu 13.04
- Meteorite version 0.6.11
- Meteor Release 0.6.5.1

Comment: So, I took the local package Errors from the Microscope project (Discover Meteor book project) and copied it into above project's packages folder.  It immediately does not work.  The Errors package was NOT in Microscope.smart.json or smart.lock.   Both projects are 
Meteorite version 0.6.11
Release 0.6.5.1
In Microscope, I see no other source ref for Errors.  Is this a library version problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue after migrating to 0.6.5 -

You only get 'exported' variables from packages you explicitly "use"; Packages "use" other packages by calling `.use` inside `Package.on_use`, **projects "use" packages by adding them to `.meteor/packages`**

Additionally, it seems to be quite picky about exporting variables, and wont currently export ones preceded with `this.`

Comment: Nathan, I thought I knew those rules, so it's something in the syntax details I am doing wrong.  I've looked at and copied working packages, but they are installed through Atmosphere, so I wonder if there is a configuration problem I have with local packages.

Comment: Do you have a sample local package config you could share?

Comment: I've noticed even packages installed via meteorite / atmosphere wouldn't add themselves to the .meteor/packages file - so I would double check that it's in that list.

Comment: I have an example project from the book 'Discover Meteor' that uses local packages, and it does not have any mention in the project smart.json or smart.lock.

Comment: Okay - I've checked out your repo and forked it - I had three issues to get your code running: Added meteor version to smart.json to run with meteorite (not necessary), added package name to .meteor/packages, and changed variable from 'this.MyName' to just 'MyName'